Are these equivalent? $∀xP(x) \land ∃xQ(x) \equiv ∃x∀y(P(y) \land Q(x))$ and also this $∀xP(x) \lor ∃xQ(x) \equiv ∃x∀y(P(y) \lor Q(x))$
I got these equivalences from a textbook:
$\forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x) \equiv \forall x \forall y (P(x) \lor Q(y))$ where all quantifiers have the same nonempty domain.
$\forall x P(x) \land \exists x Q(x)\equiv \forall x \exists y (P(x) \land Q(y))$ where all quantifiers have the
same nonempty domain.
$\forall x P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x) \equiv \forall x \exists y (P(x) \lor Q(y))$ where all quantifiers have the same nonempty domain.
But considering the commutative laws for $\land$ and $\lor$, I started thinking whether these were also true:

$∀xP(x) \land ∃xQ(x) \equiv ∃x∀y(P(y) \land Q(x))$
$∀xP(x) \lor ∃xQ(x) \equiv ∃x∀y(P(y) \lor Q(x))$

It doesn't make sense to me because of the property of order of quantifiers.
But to show the equivalence of the first one, we only need an $x$ to be true and for all to be true, and both hold it. And for being false that there is no $x$ or that not all $y$ meets P(y), which still holds it.
The second one requires almost the same logic as last one but taking into consideration that it is a disjunction.
So are they really equivalent, or I am missing something?
And how does the order of quantifiers make sense here?
If I am missing some concept please point it out (got here from learning to convert to prenex form without using prenex laws and instead using the basic properties).

Please use MathJax

Please format your formulas.

Typically, the order of quantifiers matters. That is, in general: $\forall x \exists y \phi(x,y)$ is not equivalent to $\exists y \forall x \phi(x,y)$, where $\phi(x,y)$ is some formula involving variables $x$ and $y$.
So, you are right to be concerned about this.
However, in this case it works out just fine. To be specific: as long as $P(x)$ does not have any free occurrences of variable $y$, and as long as $Q(y)$ does not have any free occurrences of variable $x$, then all the equivalences you mention hold true.
And that is because of the Prenex Laws that allow you to pull out quantifiers under certain conditions:
Prenex Laws
Where $\varphi$ is any formula and where $x$ is not a free variable in $\psi$:
$ \forall x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \land \psi)$
$  \psi \land \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \land \varphi)$
$ \exists x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \land \psi)$
$  \psi \land \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \land \varphi)$
$ \forall x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \lor \psi)$
$  \psi \lor \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \lor \varphi)$
$ \exists x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \lor \psi)$
$  \psi \lor \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \lor \varphi)$
$ \forall x \ \varphi \to \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \to \psi)$
$  \psi \to \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \to \varphi)$
$ \exists x \ \varphi \to \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \to \psi)$
$  \psi \to \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \to \varphi)$
We also need two more elementary equivalences, that state that you can systematically replace variables with a different variable:
$\forall x \ P(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall y \ P(y)$
$\exists x \ P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \ P(y)$
With these equivalences, we can show $\forall x P(x) \lor \exists x \ Q(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \exists y (P(x) \lor Q(y))$:
$\forall x P(x) \lor \exists x \ Q(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{Change variables}$
$\forall x P(x) \lor \exists y \ Q(y) \Leftrightarrow \text{Prenex}$
$\forall x (P(x) \lor \exists y \ Q(y)) \Leftrightarrow \text{Prenex}$
$\forall x \exists y (P(x) \lor Q(y))$
However, changing the order in which we use the Prenex pull out the quantifiers, we can also show $\forall x P(x) \lor \exists x \ Q(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(y))$:
$\forall x P(x) \lor \exists x \ Q(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{Change variables}$
$\forall x P(x) \lor \exists y \ Q(y) \Leftrightarrow \text{Prenex}$
$\exists y (\forall x P(x) \lor  \ Q(y)) \Leftrightarrow \text{Prenex}$
$\exists y \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(y))$
Hence, we have shown that $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \lor Q(y)) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(y))$
So yes, under certain conditions the quantifier order doesn't matter .. but these are effectively the same conditions of the Prenex Laws. So no, the equivalences you list here are not any more basic than the Prenex Laws (in fact, they are more complicated). You just failed to note those conditions. And no, you can't really reduce the Prenex Laws to other more 'basic' properties either: they are really as basic as they come in terms of the interactions between quantifiers and the main connective of the formula being quantified.
